# Typescript - inherit duplicated constructor in all derived classes using generics

Tags: typescript

I have some classes that have identical constructor (partial field assignment). I don't want to write a lot of duplicated constructor so I come up with:

```
class Base<T> {
    constructor(properties: Partial<T> = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, properties);
    }
}

class Child {
    data: number[] = []

    ownMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

var test = new Base<Child>({data: [1,2,3]}); // Base: {"data": [1,2,3]}
```

This works, but the instances created are all `Base` instead of `Child`. Is there a way to make each derived class construct itself instead of `Base`?

```
class Child extends Base<Child> {
    data: number[] = []

    ownMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

var test = new Child({data: [1,2,3]}); // Child: {"data": []}
```

This does not work.

```
class Child extends Base<Child> {
    data!: number[]
    isOpen: boolean

    ownMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

var test = new Child({data: [1,2,3]}); // Child: {"data": [1,2,3]}
```

This works partially, that `Partial` does not make sense as if you are not specifying a field it will not be in the object (e.g. `isOpen`)

Comment: Does the Child class extend Base?

Comment: @catgirlkelly Hey see my update

Comment: [What about not giving `data` an initializer?](https://tsplay.dev/wgg0Bw)

Comment: @catgirlkelly Then `Partial` has no clue. You have to provide full information at each initialization

Comment: Constructors are inherented in JavaScript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes but you got type checking in TS so the instance is kinda sealed

Comment: Not so. TypeScript models the JavaScript inheritance in the type system. Also classes may not be sealed.